# How to efficiently join large pyspark dataframes and small python list for some NLP results on databricks

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am working on NLP by SparkNLP and SparkML on databricks.

I used LDA (from SparkML) to do the topic modeling and got the following topics.

It is a pyspark dataframe (df1):

```
  df1:

  t_id word_index  weights
   0   [0, 2, 3] [0.2105, 0.116, 0.18]
   1   [1, 4, 6] [0.15, 0.05, 0.36]

 "t_id" is topic id.
 "weights" is the weight value of each word with index in "word_index"

 The "word_index" in df1 corresponds to the location of each word in the list (lt).

 df1 is small with not more than 100 rows.
```

I have a word list (lt): it is python list

```
  lt:
  ['like', 'book', 'music', 'bike', 'great', 'pen', 'laptop']
  
  lt has about 20k words.
```

I have another large pyspark dataframe (df2) with more than 20 million rows.
It size is 50+ GB.

df2:

```
 u_id p_id reviews
 sra  tvs  "I like this music" # some english tokens (each token can be found in "lt")  
 fbs  dvr  "The book is great"
```

I would like to assign the "t_id" (topics) in df1 to each row of df2 such that I can get a pyspark dataframe like:

```
 u_id p_id reviews               t_id the_highest_weights
 sra  tvs  "I like this music"   1    # the highest of all tokens' weights among all "t_id"s
 fbs  dvr  "The book is great"   4
```

But, one review may have multiple "t_id" (topics) because the review may have words covered by multiple "t_id".
So I have to calculate each "t_id"'s total weights such that the "t_id" with the highest total weights is assigned to the "reviews" in df2.

It is presented as "the_highest_weights" of the final result.

I do not want to use "for loops" to work on this row by row because it is not efficient for the large dataframe.

How can I use pyspark dataframe (not pandas) and vectorization (if needed) to get the result efficiently ?

thanks

Comment: Have you found the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact thing you want to compute but you will be able to tweak this answer to get what you need. Let's say you want to find for each sentence, the `t_id` with the maximum score (given by the sum of the weights of its tokens).

You can start by generating a dataframe that associates each word to its index.

```py
df_lt = spark.createDataFrame([(i, lt[i]) for i in 
                      range(0, len(lt))], ['word_index', 'w'])
```

Then, we will flatten df1 so that each line contains a `t_id` index, a word index and the corresponding weight. For this, we can use a UDF. Note that in spark >= 2.4 you may use `array_union` and `create_map` instead but since `df1` is small, using a UDF won't be a problem.

```py
def create_pairs(index, weights):
    return [(index[i], weights[i]) for i in range(0, len(index))]
create_pairs_udf = udf(create_pairs, ArrayType(StructType([
                         StructField(IntegerType(), 'word_index'),
                         StructField(DoubleType(), 'weight')
                   ])))

df1_exp = df1\
    .select('t_id', explode(create_pairs_udf(df1['word_index'], df1['weights']))
                       .alias('pair'))\
    .select('t_id', 'pair.word_index', 'pair.weight')
```

Finally, the main work is done on `df2`, the large dataframe. We start by exploding the sentence to get on word per line (+ the `u_id` and `p_id`). Then we need to join with `df_lt` to translate words into indices. Then, by joining with `df1_exp`, we associate each word index to its weight. Then, we group by all the indices (including `t_id`) to compute the sum of the weights and group again to select the best `t_id` for each sentence.

To speed up things, we can hint spark to broadcast `df_lt` and `df1_exp` that are small to avoid shuffling `df2` which is large.

The code looks like this:

```py
df2\
    .select("u_id", "p_id", explode(split(df2['reviews'], "\\s+")).alias("w"))\
    .join(broadcast(df_lt), ['w'])\
    .drop('w')\
    .join(broadcast(df1_exp), ['word_index'])\
    .groupBy('u_id', 'p_id', 't_id')\
    .agg(sum('weight').alias('score'))\
    .withColumn('t_id', struct('score', 't_id'))\
    .groupBy('u_id', 'p_id')\
    .agg(max('t_id').alias('t_id'))\
    .select('u_id', 'p_id', 't_id.score', 't_id.t_id')\
    .show()
```

```
+----+----+------+----+
|u_id|p_id| score|t_id|
+----+----+------+----+
| fbs| dvr|   0.2|   1|
| sra| tvs|0.3265|   0|
+----+----+------+----+
```